# how to run code part from an active configuration button Radio

Tags: odoo-8, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9, odoo-view

how to run code part from an active configuration button Radio
I already created button radio

```py
class PurchaseConfig(models.TransientModel):

_inherit = 'purchase.config.settings'

groupe_purchase_grouping = fields.Selection([
    (0, 'Active'),
    (1, 'Desactive')
    ], "Purchase grouping")
```

the function that I can execute when click on activate

```py
class ProcurementOrder(models.Model):    
_inherit = 'procurement.order'

def _make_po_get_domain(self, partner):
    res = super(ProcurementOrder, self)._make_po_get_domain(partner)
    resr = list()
    supplier=[]
    for r in res:
        if r[0]=="partner_id":
            l=("partner_id","=",False)
            resr.append(l)
            continue
        resr.append(r)
    resr = tuple(resr)
    return resr
```

Comment: Hi, you can use **onchange**

Comment: how to use onchange?

Comment: You can try this    **@api.onchange('groupe_purchase_grouping')
    def onchange(self):  
        procurement.order = self.env['procurement.order']**

Comment: I do not think so , how to activate and deactivate I have two different modules

Comment: You have to add  **onchange** in **purchase.config.settings**

Comment: procurement.order = self.env['procurement.order'] ??

Comment: not yet understood your solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158091/discussion-between-kaka-recardo-and-karara-mohamed).